# Max Range and Highest value of Number Column in all tables in a Oracle Database

Tags: oracle

I'm using the below query to get the Max Range of all the Columns of all tables in a Oracle Database

```
    select OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_PRECISION,(POWER(10,DATA_PRECISION) -1) 
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS where OWNER = 'MASTER' and DATA_TYPE = 'NUMBER' and 
DATA_PRECISION is NOT NULL order by TABLE_NAME ASC;


OWNER    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME   DATA_PRECISION  (POWER(10,DATA_PRECISION) -1)
MASTER    TABLE_1      COL_1            7            9999999
MASTER    TABLE_1      COL_5            7            9999999
MASTER    TABLE_2      COL_3            10           9999999999
```

I am trying to get a 6th & 7th Column, which should be max of that column in that particular table and difference between Max Range( i.e (POWER(10,DATA_PRECISION) -1)) and actual max value in the table.

Ex:

```
OWNER    TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME   DATA_PRECISION  (POWER(10,DATA_PRECISION) -1)   MAX_VALUE     DIFF
MASTER    TABLE_1      COL_1            7            9999999                         9994637     5362
MASTER    TABLE_1      COL_5            7            9999999                         9997637     2362
MASTER    TABLE_2      COL_3            10           9999999999                    8933999999    1066000000
```

How to achieve this ?

Would i be able to join tables, using TABLE_NAME ?

Bet, this would be helpful to a lot of people.

Comment: I don't think you can do that w/o using "execute immediate" maybe?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to go about this is to write a small function that you can provide a table name and column like so:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_max_value (p_table_name VARCHAR2, p_column VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    v_query VARCHAR2(1000);
    v_max_value NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_query := 'SELECT MAX (' || p_column ||') FROM '
        ||  p_table_name ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query
        INTO v_max_value;
    RETURN v_max_value;
END;
```

And then a slightly modified version of your query above:

```
 SELECT   owner,
         table_name,
         column_name,
         data_precision,
         (POWER(10,data_precision) -1) ,
         get_max_value (owner || '.' || table_name, column_name) max_val 
FROM    all_tab_columns   
WHERE   1 = 1 
AND     owner = 'MASTER' 
AND     data_type = 'NUMBER'   
AND     data_precision is NOT NULL 
AND     table_name NOT LIKE  '%$%'
ORDER BY c.table_name ASC
```

Just be careful, depending on the number of your tables and the number of rows in each, execution can take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Convert DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.HIGH_VALUE to the maximum value  as described in [this post by Jonathan Lewis.](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2006/11/29/low_value-high_value/)

The maximum and minimum values are recorded when table statistics are gathered.  If the default estimate percent is used, and the statistics were gathered recently, the value will be accurate.

```
create or replace function raw_to_num(i_raw raw) 
return number 
as 
    m_n number; 
begin 
    dbms_stats.convert_raw_value(i_raw,m_n); 
    return m_n; 
end; 
/  

select owner,table_name,column_name,data_precision
    ,(power(10,data_precision) -1) max_range
    ,raw_to_num(high_value) max_value
    ,(power(10,data_precision) -1) - raw_to_num(high_value) diff
from dba_tab_columns
where data_type = 'NUMBER'
    and owner = user
    --Add conditions for specific users and tables.
order by owner, table_name, column_name;
```